# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor - Is it possible to turn a String into a Hyperlink using Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to turn a String into a Hyperlink using Html.Raw. What would the code for this be?
I'm trying to embed an `<a>` Tag into a Razor Page with the following:

```
@{
  string strText = "<title>Link Test</title><a class=\"nav-link text-dark\" target=\"_new\" asp- 
  area=\"Test\" asp-controller=\"Test\" asp-action=\"ViewFile\" asp-route-Id=1> View File Test</a>";  
 }
@Html.Raw(strText)
```

My page just shows "View File Test" without a link.

[image]

When I view the page source in my browser I see the following:

```
<title>Link Test</title><a class="nav-link text-dark" target="_new" asp-area="Test" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="ViewFile" asp-route-Id=1> View File Test</a>
```

[image]

When I copy the above and paste it to my razor page,  all works well.

Just for fun, I have also tried the following and get the same result:

```
@{
  string strText = "<title>Link Test</title><a class=\"nav-link text-dark\" target=\"_new\" asp- 
  area=\"Test\" asp-controller=\"Test\" asp-action=\"ViewFile\" asp-route-Id=1> View File Test</a>";  
 }
<text>@strText</text>
```

The following example below works fine, but not the above. I thought maybe it had to do with the embedded quotes

```
@{
  string strText = "My Text <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">My link</a>.";  
 }
@Html.Raw(strText)
```

Answer (score 2):

For [HtmlHelper.Raw Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) , the parameter is the HTML markup, however `asp-area` and `asp-controller` are the [Anchor Tag Helper attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#anchor-tag-helper-attributes). HTML code, or actually any text, returned from methods is not processed by the Razor engine, so you cannot use HTML tag helpers here.

You could try to use `@Html.ActionLink` or `@Url.Action` helper methods as shown:

```
@{
   string strText = "<title>Link Test</title><a class=\"nav-link text-dark\" target=\"_new\" href=\""+Url.Action("ViewFile","Test" ,new { Area="Test",Id=1})+"\" >View File Test</a>";
}
```

the generated url will be `https://localhost:44348/Test/Test/ViewFile?Id=1`.

register routes as below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "areaRoute",
               // if you don't have such an area named as `areaName` already, 
               //    don't make the part of `{area}` optional by `{area:exists}`
               pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
       endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35579040/10201850

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147778/10201850

Answer (score 2):

The main reason your solution with asp tags will not work because they (tag helpers) are **compiled** at run time into your existing views.
At runtime compilation, your string is getting compiled as a string and tags inside that are being ignored obviously because compiler is unaware of them. 
But when you use html attributes like anchor tag, it will work fine because that gets parsed by your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that in Razor, asp- prefixed attributes for tags are somehow rendered at server side. This properties/attributes are not from HTML5.

Answer: Yes, it is possible, but it must be valid HTML.